# Suddenly ggplot Crashes R studio, Any suggestions?

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio-server

Suddenly ggplot began causing errors and froze my base system
a reboot gave me the following:
"R Session Error", "The previous R session was abnormally terminated due to an unexpected crash"

I am using RStudio Server

In an effort to solve the problem I created a new VM (ubuntu 20.04 on windows 10)
upgraded to R studio Version 1.4.1106
I have upgraded to  R 4.1
and installed new packages (tidyverse) which is critical to the work but
still getting a crash.

Below is a very simple test script that fails with the error noted above
As noted this is on a fresh install

TEST Script

```r
library(tidyverse)
data(iris)
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, colour=Species)) +
  geom_point()
```

Comment: hmm found this https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/9373  The potential solution is Downgrading to r-4.0.5-4 or running a preview version of R studio https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/ .

Comment: Same issue with R4.1, ggplot and RStudio (running on Limux Mint 20.1), No issue with the R console. The code provided by LHooper is the minimum to reproduce the issue.
The suggestion to use a preview version of RStudio solves the issue for now. Thanks.

Comment: @LHooper this worked for me. Would you post it as answer pls?

Answer (score 3):

Rstudio has now updated to release 1.4.1717, which solves the ggplot crashing error.

If you must use Rstudio 1.4.1106 and have upgraded to r 4.1. You can resolve the ggplot crash issue by downgrading to R 4.05

However, the optimum solution is to upgrade to Rstudio 1.4.1717